# Nested URI's with multiple categories

Tags: url, routing

Was looking for some insight/recommendations on a URI structure for a ecommerce site. The site has thousands of entries & hundreds of categories. A entry can have multiple categories assigned across different category groups. What is the best way to format single entry pages? Do I just have a clean break that all products have a `product/view` template or do I try and nest them under each category:

> http://domain.com/category_group_a/category_a/example_product

which could also be:

> http://domain.com/category_group_b/category_b/example_product

If I go the category route, then there is the potential of having duplicate pages under each category the entry is assigned to. Also, this makes it difficult generating URL structures from say a search result page. Ideally, the nested route would be best for SEO, but structuring URI's so they are consistent is going to be a challenge.

Answer (score 2):

With my limited understanding of how your site is configured:

I would use the URI structure of url.com/products/cat_group/cat/product_url_title

That way you can do this with a single template and control the view from the index.html in the products.group using the Low Seg2Cat plugin with the following if statement:

```
{if segment_3 == "" && segment_2 == ""}

This could return all products code given the cat group id by passing in the {segment_2_category_group_id} into the category_group param in the ee entries tag.

{if:elseif segment_3 == "" && segment_2 != ""}

This could return all products code given the cat id with passing in the {segment_3_category_id} into the category_group param in the ee entries tag.

{if:else}
```

This would be the code for a products

```
{/if}
```

seg2cat - http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/docs

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have done something very similar to this, but performance wise it's not the most efficient (https://gist.github.com/Siebird/4089096) and ran into numerous issues with duplicate content under different categories. I solved this by using Solspace's primary category plugin, but it's not the most ideal setup

Comment: Siebird, Can you share what you decided upon - have a similar project and would also like to avoid the category structure (3rd party addon use). Could the "new" Template Routes help? –

Answer (score 1):

It's always going to be subjective but I'd go with the simple approach of never having category information in the URL for anything other than a filtered listing page. It's the kind of thing that seems like a good idea at the time, but every decision you make, every new development that happens, every redesign of the site that happens, it will probably come back to haunt you.

Comment: Thanks James. This basically sums up why I asked this question to see if there truly is a sound/solid nested URI structure. I'll see how this thread plays out over the next couple of days to see if there is a clever solution.